# Should I Use Debug NPM Module in Production?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a reason I should not be using the [debug npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) in production? I think it would be helpful to be able to access these logs in production in case something went wrong with the payment flow.

Example debug statements:

```
debug(`Begin Create Charge for user ${user.id}`);
```

Comment: Useful messages are `logs`, not `debug`

Comment: How would you implement `logs` @vp_arth

Comment: Nevermind @vp_arth I have found an async library for node called winston. I think that will do the trick. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) process manager. It will automatically write all your `debug` logs to log files. More info about pm2 logs: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#log-facilities

Comment: first post your answer and then references.